# magento database structure?

Tags: magento

Currently am working with magento project..
in which i have stucked on the point ..
that is when admin add any subcategory/category
by

Manage category -> custome design

here its gives two option like

**Active from** and **Active to**..
can anyone, who know about magento database, tell me where or in which table this two value store

Thanks for any suggestion or help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've listed the attributes for catalog categories below. Since categories are an EAV type, you'll need to look in a particular subtable to get your values. In this case, `custom_design_from` and `custom_design_to` are datetime values, and the name of your entity is `catalog_category_entity`, so the table you want is `catalog_category_entity_datetime`.

Next problem you'll find is getting the right attribute ID. Since they're liable to change, here's the SQL query to run in order to grab them:

```
select attribute_id, attribute_code from eav_attribute where entity_type_id = 3 and attribute_code in ('custom_design_from', 'custom_design_to');
```

I get 52 and 53, but YMWV. Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

```
+----------------------+--------------+
| attribute_code       | backend_type |
+----------------------+--------------+
| name                 | varchar      |
| is_active            | int          |
| url_key              | varchar      |
| description          | text         |
| image                | varchar      |
| meta_title           | varchar      |
| meta_keywords        | text         |
| meta_description     | text         |
| display_mode         | varchar      |
| landing_page         | int          |
| is_anchor            | int          |
| path                 | static       |
| position             | static       |
| all_children         | text         |
| path_in_store        | text         |
| children             | text         |
| url_path             | varchar      |
| custom_design        | varchar      |
| custom_design_apply  | int          |
| custom_design_from   | datetime     |
| custom_design_to     | datetime     |
| page_layout          | varchar      |
| custom_layout_update | text         |
| level                | static       |
| children_count       | static       |
| available_sort_by    | text         |
| default_sort_by      | varchar      |
| include_in_menu      | int          |
+----------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: That really belongs as a separate question (and needs more space to answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Active from is an attribute whose attribute_code is custom_design_from(attribute_id 57) and Active To is an attribute whose attribute_code(attribute_id 58) is custom_design_to.
This both attributes value are stored in database table `catalog_category_entity_datetime`.
```

Check above table with row like value of entity_id is your category id, attribute_id is 57 and active from value is store in `value` field of table same  active to value is stored in `value` field with entity_id is your category id, attribute_id is 58.